# Invalid parameter given. A valid $fileId[tmp_name] is expected. magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2.4.1

While uploading a image getting error

Invalid parameter given. A valid $fileId[tmp_name] is expected.

[image]

Comment: Are your magento setup on bitnami server?

Answer (score 2):

In Magento\Framework\File\Uploader.php
comment the following method inside _setUpload FileId($fileId) function

// $this->validateFileId($fileId);

it's work for me

Comment: this is core file, so this is not right way , if we comment it's stop validating for whole website

Comment: for local server it's works for  me
Where do you get the error local or live ?